# conditional statements in where clause of SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a fairly complicated SQL query that hits multiple tables from an Oracle database. I'm trying to bring in data from a new table that has two key columns and looks kind of like this:

```
key1  key2  date
001         2016-06-12
001   0001  2016-06-13
002         2016-06-14
003         2016-06-15
003   0001  2016-06-16
...
```

There is a NULL key2 record for every unique key1 value, which is supposed to be the default if key2 doesn't exist. My current query is:

```
SELECT ..., (variables from other tables)
       newtable.date
  FROM ..., (other database tables)
       newtable
 WHERE ..., (whole bunch of table links)
   AND newtable.key1 = keytable.key1
   AND (newtable.key2 = keytable.key2 OR newtable.key2 IS NULL)
```

This gives me everything in newtable, but I need a unique record for each key1 value. I want the query to return the date for the non-NULL key2 record, if there is one, otherwise return the date for the NULL key2 record.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Show us what is your expected result. And if you want a full solution we need other tables information. If you think we dont need other tables then provide a simple problem. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides `KEEP FIRST` to pick a value from the "best" record of a list. You want the best record's date. You can get it with `KEEP FIRST` in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  <columns from other tables>,
  (
    select max(n.date) keep (dense_rank first order by n.key2 nulls last)
    from newtable n
    where n.key1 = k.key1
     and (n.key2 = k.key2 OR n.key2 is null)
  ) as newtable_date
FROM keytable k
JOIN <other database tables>
WHERE ...
```

Comment: That was a bit messier than I expected, but it worked. Thanks!